# Extract tables from PDF to Azure search

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to index pdf contents to azure search index. For that I am using the function apps for analyzeForm and extractTables project in the Azure Search Power Skills GitHub repository.

The AnalyzeForm has field mappings using which I am able to map the output fields to corresponding Azure search Index fields.
But I also want to extract the table contents for which I will have to use ExtractTables API. The API returns the table record in this form :

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "recordId": "record1",
            "data": {
                "tables": [
                    {
                        "page_number": 1,
                        "row_count": 3,
                        "column_count": 4,
                        "cells": [
                            {
                                "text": "Item",
                                "rowIndex": 0,
                                "colIndex": 0,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Quantity",
                                "rowIndex": 0,
                                "colIndex": 1,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Rate",
                                "rowIndex": 0,
                                "colIndex": 2,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Amount",
                                "rowIndex": 0,
                                "colIndex": 3,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Iphone 12 (64 GB)",
                                "rowIndex": 1,
                                "colIndex": 0,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "1",
                                "rowIndex": 1,
                                "colIndex": 1,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "$600.00",
                                "rowIndex": 1,
                                "colIndex": 2,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "$600.00",
                                "rowIndex": 1,
                                "colIndex": 3,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "MI 10 (6 GB)",
                                "rowIndex": 2,
                                "colIndex": 0,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "1",
                                "rowIndex": 2,
                                "colIndex": 1,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "$300.00",
                                "rowIndex": 2,
                                "colIndex": 2,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "$300.00",
                                "rowIndex": 2,
                                "colIndex": 3,
                                "confidence": 1.0,
                                "is_header": false
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I map the data extracted from tables to index it into Azure search? Is there any way I can add this as a custom skill? If yes, what will be the index schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 3 ways to transpose a skill output you can either use a shaper skill, inline shaping or use a custom skill. In this instance I'll agree with @Thiago that the best option would be to use a custom skill as a shaper will not allow you to pick just the specific column value from the table result.

If you are using the Power Skills, you could edit the skill to return a response that maps to your index field definition. Assuming your index field looks like:

```
    {
      "name": "Items",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)",
      "analyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "Item_Id",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "facetable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "key": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "searchable": false,
          "sortable": false,
          "analyzer": null,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "synonymMaps": [],
          "fields": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Quantity",
          "type": "Edm.Int64",
          "facetable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "sortable": false,
          "analyzer": null,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "synonymMaps": [],
          "fields": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Rate",
          "type": "Edm.Double",
          "facetable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "sortable": false,
          "analyzer": null,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "synonymMaps": [],
          "fields": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Amount",
          "type": "Edm.Double",
          "facetable": false,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": false,
          "sortable": false,
          "analyzer": null,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "synonymMaps": [],
          "fields": []
        }
      ]
    }
```

You could edit your skill to return a JSON object like:

```
{
    "items" : [
        {
            "item": "Iphone 12",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 1000,
            "amount: 1000
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Azure Function as a Custom Skill. Just map the fields from ExtractTables to the expected Custom Skill fields:

```
private class OutputRecord
{
    public class OutputRecordData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public string Description { get; set; } = "";
        public string Source { get; set; } = "";
        public string SourceUrl { get; set; } = "";
        public string LicenseAttribution { get; set; } = "";
        public string LicenseUrl { get; set; } = "";
    }

    public class OutputRecordMessage
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public string RecordId { get; set; }
    public OutputRecordData Data { get; set; }
    public List<OutputRecordMessage> Errors { get; set; }
    public List<OutputRecordMessage> Warnings { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-create-custom-skill-example